# Word association: Guess the movie title!

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, movies

So I was inspired by Braincraft's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmN0_erGP7M) about Remote Associates Test so I thought I'd give it a try here on Puzzling.

I kind of tweaked with the mechanics a little bit and included words that are *related* but really off if you are not into *popular culture*.

The **answer (5 words)** for each group of words would be the clue for a movie.

pie, eye, Adam

Hermanos, road, cow

bumps, chase, golden

sly, Ylvis, swipe

Stark, bank, blind

Comment: So each group of words yields one word for the final answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a final solution, but not a confident one:

1. pie, eye, Adam

   > Apple (Apple pie, Apple of my Eye, Adam's Apple or the story of Adam and Eve from whence it came)
2. Hermanos, road, cow

   > Chicken (Hermanos Locos from Breaking Bad had a chicken mascot, chicken crossing the road, and the cartoon Cow and Chicken)
3. bumps, chase, golden

   > Goose (goosebumps, wild goose chase, and the Golden Goose from Jack and the Beanstalk)
4. sly, Ylvis, swipe

   > Fox (sly as a fox, What Does the Fox Say, and ... Swiper the fox from Dora the Explorer?  I prefer SpryFox, who makes mobile games)
5. Stark, bank, blind

   > Rob (Robb Stark from Game of Thrones, rob a bank, or rob someone blind)

I don't know how they go together, but if I was going to make a guess...

> Fantastic Mr. Fox?

Comment: [Los Pollos Hermanos](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Los_Pollos_Hermanos) was the establishment Gus Fring used as a front for his drug dealing in Breaking Bad

Comment: That was fast! This is the exact answer except for the Hermanos Locos thing, it was suppose to be Los Pollos Hermanos, which means "chicken brothers" in Spanish, just like @CodeNewbie said.

Comment: Ah, true... I knew that, but got it confused with El Pollo Loco, the real-life chain of which I was always reminded.

Answer (score 2):

Still haven't gotten it but:

Pie, eye, Adam

> Apple:
>
>  Apple pie, apple of my eye, Adam's apple

Bumps, chase, golden

> Goose:
>
>  Goose bumps, wild goose chase, golden goose

Sly, ylvis, swipe

> fox:
>
>  Sly fox, what does the fox say, swiper