# Word association: Guess the movie title 2!

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, knowledge

In my [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/36731/10686), I tried making my own word association test with a twist and I guess it was too easy.

This time I started with 54 words, each 3-word color coded  group will correspond to the answer on the 1st level (A1, B1..); after completing first layer, letter-coded 3-word group will be the clue to the 2nd level (A2, B2...); which then will be the clue to the movie title. There will be six words at the end, words/ clue that are significant to the film.

I only have one answer in mind, although there could be other possible answers, I don't think it will make sense at the end.

[image]

Comment: [related](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40018/clue-web-1-lets-start), [related](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40093/clue-web-2-a-barrel-of-fun)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The movie is:**

> **Stranger than Fiction**

**First level:**

> A1 is death + sin + break
>  B1 is time + look + think
>  C1 is pine + big + orange
>  D1 is dark + error + sit     — thanks OP for sit
>  E1 is mail + passive + box   — thanks @Will for mail & passive
>  F1 is fortune + monster + sharp

**Second level:**

> A2 is tax
>  B2 is watch     — thanks OP
>  C2 is crush?
>  D2 is comedy?
>  E2 is voice    — thanks @Will again
>  F2 is cookie

Comment: Looks like your missing E1 would be "passive"

Comment: Also, "natural" should instead be "mail" and E2 is "voice"

Comment: 70% done! Keep going!

Comment: Correct! Just polish C and D, B2 is supposed to be "watch".  The third word on D1 is "sit"

Comment: I still don't get "care"→"sit".  The rest of these now feel right.

Comment: @Rubio I suspect that it's "sit" as in "babysit", which is caring for someone.

Answer (score 3):

#### Partial Answer

> A1: death, sin, ???
> B1: time, ???, ???
> C1: pine, ???, orange
> D1: ???, error, ???
> E1: ???, ???, box
> F1: fortune, monster, ???

Comment: The remaining C1 _could be_ "big" & the A1 is probably "break"

Comment: Whoops. Didn't see either of your answers :)